# ffmpeg encode in all-i mode h264 and h265 streams

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, h.265

Which params I can use to obtain a transcode all-i based? No B and P frames?

I know that this is not efficient for compression purposes but this is not my case now.

I guess i have to fiddle a bit with **-x264-params** or **-x265-params** but I don't know the switches to do it :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For H264

```
ffmpeg -i input -c:v libx264 -intra output
```

For H265, seems no alias or preset has been set yet

```
ffmpeg -i input -c:v libx265 -x265-params frame-threads=4:keyint=1:ref=1:no-open-gop=1:weightp=0:weightb=0:cutree=0:rc-lookahead=0:bframes=0:scenecut=0:b-adapt=0:repeat-headers=1 output
```

H265 code <s>stolen</s>borrowed from [here](https://superuser.com/q/935930/114058).

Comment: The commands for h265 can be used for h264 as well including some tuning ? Also, can I use `frame-threads=1` instead of 4 ? Thanks :)

Comment: Should be no problem, on both counts.

Comment: Thank you :) Also I was wondering if `repeat-headers=1` is really necessary.

Comment: Since `keyint=1` seems to generate the same file, are the other parameters necessary (`scenecut=0` only speeds up the processing by saving the frame comparison analysis for instance)?

Comment: for ffmpeg 5.0 you'll need to do `-g 1` instead of `-intra`. I.e `ffmpeg -i input -c:v libx264 -g 1 output`